# Specify boost libraries for each Qt Kit

Tags: qt, boost, qt-creator

I know how to specify boost libraries in .pro file. But if I want to build a project after switching to another compiler, I need to change the path. I want proper boost library to be selected when I switch kit in Qt creator.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use an environment variable for the location of the boost library, e.g. `BOOST_ROOT` and then read it in the .pro file:

```
# Ensure that the BOOST_ROOT environment variable has been set
BOOST_ROOT = $$(BOOST_ROOT)
isEmpty(BOOST_ROOT) {
  error("Please set BOOST_ROOT to the location of the Boost libraries")
} else {
  message(Using Boost from: $$BOOST_ROOT)
}

INCLUDEPATH += $$BOOST_ROOT
LIBS += -L$${BOOST_ROOT}/stage/lib
```

When you switch compiler kits you can change the environment variable under `Projects->Build Environment`. QtCreator will store the change to the environment variable for the compiler kit build.

So be sure to change the environment variable for both the `debug` and `release` builds for each compiler kit.